# Converting string to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am making a asynchronous request to my server and its returning an array as a string.
The string is in the proper array form for example:

```
"[{"spo":"I"},{"spo":"hate"},{"spo":"computers"}]"
```

Is there a way to simply create an array from this string?

Comment: The builtin JSON function is best if available, you can also use *eval*: `var x = '[1,2,3]';alert(eval(x));`. That's how it was done in pre-JSON browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a JSON string, you can create an array from it with:

```
JSON.parse('[{"spo":"I"},{"spo":"hate"},{"spo":"computers"}]')
```

In older browsers you may need to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: JSON.parse will return an Array object?

Comment: Yes it does, if the provided string is an encoded array which now is.

Comment: My issue come from IE6. Fixed it as soon as I got you hint.

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery, you can get it as array by specifying the dataType as Json. 
See [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Same as in Mootools and includes support for IE6

Comment: Cool, include a 90k script to do something that can be done with built-in functions.

Comment: I meant to say if they are using jQuery. And jQuery is not 90k, just 31KB (minified).

Answer (score 0):

The string happens to correspond to the JSON format, so you can use a JSON parser to turn it into an array, for example the JSON parser in jQuery:

```
var myLittleArray = $.parseJSON(theJsonString);
```